# Adaptive Card text overflow in Microsoft Teams Android app

Tags: android, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards, teams-toolkit

I have the following JSON code for my adaptive card:

```json
{
  "type": "AdaptiveCard",
  "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
  "version": "1.3",
  "body": [
    {
      "type": "Container",
      "items": [
        {
          "type": "TextBlock",
          "text": "Awesome! ",
          "wrap": true,
          "size": "large",
          "weight": "bolder"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "TextBlock",
      "text": "Let's add some tags and notes to make it more memorable",
      "wrap": true
    },
    {
      "type": "Input.ChoiceSet",
      "choices": [
        {
          "title": "Work",
          "value": "1"
        },
        {
          "title": "Kids",
          "value": "2"
        }
      ],
      "id": "tags",
      "label": "What influences your current mood?",
      "style": "expanded",
      "isMultiSelect": true
    },
    {
      "type": "TextBlock",
      "text": "Any notes that you would like to add",
      "wrap": true
    },
    {
      "type": "Input.Text",
      "placeholder": "Write something...",
      "id": "notes",
      "isMultiline": true
    },
    {
      "type": "Input.Text",
      "value": "1",
      "id": "moodId",
      "isVisible": false
    }
  ],
  "actions": [
    {
      "type": "Action.Submit",
      "title": "Submit"
    }
  ]
}
```

But for some reason it doesn't care for the `wrap` attribute in Android (iOS is working ok). The MS Teams is refusing my submission because of the horizontal scrollbar, how can I solve this?

| iOS | Android |
| --- | --- |
| [image: iOS app] | [image: Android app] |

**Update:**
Tested on:

- Xiaomi Redmi Note 8
- Android version 11 rkq1.201004.002
- Teams version 1416/1.0.0.2021163901/1022

Comment: We have repro of this issue and raised the bug for it. Concerned team is looking into it. If there is any update we will let you know.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is fixed now. Please update your Teams version and check